# Make port 80 globally accessible

Tags: networking, server, iptables, firewall, nginx

I am trying to set up a VPS server (Ubuntu 22.04 LTS) bought from Microsoft. I am able to set up NGINX on my own by watching this [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LE_b8PiYy-A). After setting up all the configs stated in the video I ran `nginx -t` to confirm if all the setup was correct. It ran without any error. Now the main concern is in the tutorial it is using Hostinger provider which by default made port 80 public but in my VPS it is not.

After watching few blogs & questions in stack I ran the follow `sudo ufw status` command to see if HTTP & NGINX is enabled or not for which I got this.

```
root@Online-Test-UBUNTU-22-04:/# sudo ufw status
Status: active

To                         Action      From
--                         ------      ----
Nginx HTTP                 ALLOW       Anywhere
22/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80/tcp                     ALLOW       Anywhere
80                         ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx Full                 ALLOW       Anywhere
Nginx HTTP (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
22/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80/tcp (v6)                ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
80 (v6)                    ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)
Nginx Full (v6)            ALLOW       Anywhere (v6)

root@Online-Test-UBUNTU-22-04:/#
```

Below is my custom server config code stored in `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/otp`

```
server {
        listen 80;
        listen [::]:80;

        root /var/www/html;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

        server_name X.X.X.X;

        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/=404;
        }
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Have you verified [the network security group is properly configured](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/nsg-quickstart-portal)? 

Comment: Thanks @matigo, this helped. I was not aware of this. Thanks a lot again. Was stuck here for last 3 days 